# SOQL Limit Reached

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, governorlimits

Can anyone help me with why i am reaching the limit with this.

Error Message:

> System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101
>   Stack Trace Trigger.FirstInvoiceBeforeWithType: line 41, column 1

```
trigger FirstInvoiceBeforeWithType on Recurly_Invoice__c (before insert, before update) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Recurly_Invoice__c record : trigger.new) accountIds.add(record.Account__c);

    Map<Id, Datetime> earliestCloseDatesAttendance = new Map<Id, Datetime>();
    Map<Id, Datetime> earliestCloseDatesScheduling = new Map<Id, Datetime>();
    Map<Id, Datetime> earliestCloseDatesTimeClock = new Map<Id, Datetime>();

    for (AggregateResult aggregateAttendance : [
    SELECT Account__c, MIN(Closed_At__c) earliestCloseAttendance FROM Recurly_Invoice__c
    WHERE Account__c IN :accountIds AND Status__c = 'Collected' AND Subscription__r.Recurly_Subscription_Type__c = 'Attendance'
    GROUP BY Account__c
    ])
     earliestCloseDatesAttendance.put(
        (Id)aggregateAttendance.get('Account__c'),
        (Datetime)aggregateAttendance.get('earliestCloseAttendance')
    );

    for (Recurly_Invoice__c record : trigger.new)
    {
    if (record.Closed_At__c == earliestCloseDatesAttendance.get(record.Account__c))
        record.First_Invoice_Attendance__c = true;
    }

    for (AggregateResult aggregateScheduling : [
    SELECT Account__c, MIN(Closed_At__c) earliestCloseScheduling FROM Recurly_Invoice__c
    WHERE Account__c IN :accountIds AND Status__c = 'Collected' AND Subscription__r.Recurly_Subscription_Type__c = 'Scheduling'
    GROUP BY Account__c
    ])
    earliestCloseDatesScheduling.put(
        (Id)aggregateScheduling.get('Account__c'),
        (Datetime)aggregateScheduling.get('earliestCloseScheduling')
    );

    for (Recurly_Invoice__c record : trigger.new)
    {
    if (record.Closed_At__c == earliestCloseDatesScheduling.get(record.Account__c))
        record.First_Invoice_Scheduling__c = true;
    }

    for (AggregateResult aggregateTimeClock : [
    SELECT Account__c, MIN(Closed_At__c) earliestCloseTimeClock FROM Recurly_Invoice__c
    WHERE Account__c IN :accountIds AND Status__c = 'Collected' AND Subscription__r.Recurly_Subscription_Type__c = 'TimeClock'
    GROUP BY Account__c
    ])
    earliestCloseDatesTimeClock.put(
        (Id)aggregateTimeClock.get('Account__c'),
        (Datetime)aggregateTimeClock.get('earliestCloseTimeClock')
    );

    for (Recurly_Invoice__c record : trigger.new)
    {
    if (record.Closed_At__c == earliestCloseDatesTimeClock.get(record.Account__c))
        record.First_Invoice_TimeClock__c = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're querying out `Recurly_Invoice__c`, why don't you just query it once into a Map and use your Map you qualify your records

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to **include the error message**. There are a few different limits that you could reach, it seems query rows would be the most likely.

Comment: As this trigger isn't using any grossly bad patterns, the problem is likely to be its interaction with other triggers and workflows. Check the debug log to see what else is running.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I loaded 201 Recurly_Invoice__c records using the data import wizard and received no errors. I got the error from running a test class..but i still received 100% code coverage. Not sure what the error is about, but i have 100% code coverage and when i test through wizard i receive no errors.

Comment: @KeithC you were right. there was another after trigger on the account that was running multiple times and causing the error. thank you